# (Multitech mDot + Conduit) mDot keeps dropping connection to network

Tags: lora, lorawan

If anybody has experience the Multitech mDot and Conduit modules to set up  a LoRa network I could use their help.

I’ve set up a LoRa network consisting of an mDot node (plugged into a Multitech developer board, programmed using mebd compiled code) which connects to a Conduit gateway that forwards the packets to LORIOT network server.

The problem I’m having is that the mDot will for a short while connect perfectly, sending data to the gateway which is forwarded and recieved on the network server, but then unexpectedly will fail to connect to the Conduit with
`failed to join network -4:Join Error`
and will not connect for long periods of time if at all again and will do the same

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same trouble when setting *ADR = true*. When using ADR, I have to set the data rate every time that I transmit, or else it fails.

Setting ADR to *false* fixed this for me.

There were some other funky things that I saw - I wrote a wrapper for the mDot library so that I didn't have all the clunky setup in my main function. When I did that, the join was severely impacted. If you've done something similar, have your wrapper own the mDot pointer.

Not initializing the vector used to store the data you're about to send in the while loop will also cause a join fail.

Comment: Welcome to the site, you can check out the [tour] to find out more about Stack Exchange and the IoT Stack.